# How to use dynamic if condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `SQL` query as follows

```
select TransactionMode as [Modes],
TransactionCode as [Codes], 
TransactionAmount as [Amount],SubTotal,Total 
from TransactionDetails where CurrentTime> CAST(GETDATE()as date)
```

It gives o/p as follows

```
  Modes        Codes     Amount     SubTotal      Total 
  CARDS        ICICI      12         13.18        13.18
  CARDS        ICICI      200        219.7        219.7
  CARDS        ICICI      500        549.25       549.25
  BUY          COD        7000       42.898       38.67
  CARDS        SBI        400        439.4        439.4
```

I want to calculate commission on the basis of `TransactionMode` columns.I tried my query as follows

```
Declare @TransactionMode varchar(250);
set @TransactionMode='select TransactionMode from TransactionDetails'

IF @TransactionMode = 'CARDS'
    select transactioncode as [Type], count(TransactionCode) as [No of Trans], SUM(Total) as [Amount],
ABS(SUM(Subtotal-TransactionAmount)) as [Comission] from dbo.TransactionDetails  where CurrentTime> CAST(GETDATE()as date) and
     Status='Active' group by transactioncode

ELSE
   select transactioncode as [Type], count(TransactionCode) as [No of Trans], SUM(Total) as [Amount],
ABS(SUM(Subtotal-Total)) as [Comission] from dbo.TransactionDetails  
   where CurrentTime> CAST(GETDATE()as date)
    and Status='Active' group by transactioncode
```

I am expecting o/p as

```
Type  No Of Trans   Amount    Comission
COD       1         38.67      4.228
ICICI     3         782.13     70.13
SBI       1         439.4      39.4
```

Instead I am getting

```
Type  No Of Trans   Amount    Comission
COD       1         38.67      4.228
ICICI     3         782.13     0
SBI       1         439.4      0
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: your query seem to be ok and according to T-sql ,it is giving correct output.you must have over look something>if output is not correct then something wrong with your where condition.This is correct ABS(SUM(Subtotal-TransactionAmount)) as [Comission].OR SOMETHING wrong with the formula

Comment: I tried of using `ABS(SUM(Subtotal-TransactionAmount)) as [Comission] ` and `SUM(Subtotal-TransactionAmount) as [Comission] ` but getting the same result :(

Comment: `set @TransactionMode='select TransactionMode from TransactionDetails'` Little worried about this line as `@TransactionMode` will never be equals to `CARDS` and you will always execute else condition because `'select TransactionMode from TransactionDetails'` is a string not a select statement also the subquery will return more than 1 value.

Comment: Suprabhat's comment is the answer actually. Beside that, your formulas `ABS(SUM(a-b))` seem strange. This equals `ABS(SUM(a) - SUM(b))`, i.e. you subtract one sum from the other and then make this positive. Doesn't it matter whether the result is negative or positive???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your error: You fill the variable @TransactionMode with the string 'select TransactionMode from TransactionDetails'. This will never equal 'CARDS', so you always execute the ELSE branch.

Instead look at a record's transaction mode:

```
select 
  transactioncode as [Type], 
  count(transactioncode) as [No of Trans], 
  sum(total) as [Amount],
  abs(sum(case when transactionmode = 'cards' then subtotal - transactionamount 
                                              else subtotal - total end)) as [Comission] 
from dbo.transactiondetails  
where currenttime > cast(getdate() as date) 
and status = 'active' 
group by transactioncode;
```

(The formulas `abs(sum(a-b))` seem strange, by the way. Shouldn't it matter whether a result is positive or negative?)

Comment: Wow ! Well caught.But there was no error in query.My full attention was in query.